# Can a person with my ssh key get remote access to my notebook?

Tags: security, ssh, key

A colleague was helping me to generate key using `ssh-gen`, then we copied the key to server.

Can a person with my ssh key get remote access to my notebook?

That is if that RSA key is for me/my session/my notebook, can other person getting that file access to the server (I guess yes) and to my notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not to your notebook, but probably yes to the server. You have generated an RSA key pair (a public and a private key). If you did it correctly, you have copied the public key to the remote server. The private key should be on your notebook (and should not be shared with anyone else other than yourself - think of it as an equivalent to a password).

Your public key that you transferred to the remote server is in the `authorized_keys` file. When you are trying to login to the server, in simple terms, you are actually verifying to it that you are in possession of the private key that corresponds to the authorised public key.

Therefore, someone who has your public key cannot login to your computer. If your private key has been compromised, someone may be able to login to your computer, if the corresponding public key is in your `authorized_keys` file. This might be hard as well, since private keys are usually encrypted and you need to put a password in order to decrypt it. During `ssh-gen` you must have been asked to set that password. However, someone who has compromised your private key might also be able to access the server and impersonate you.

If you are unsure whether your private key is compromised, probably the best idea is to delete the key pair from your computer, generate a new one, delete the public key from the server, and upload your new one. If you are using this public key on many servers the task will be long.

Here are also some useful instructions regarding the permissions that you should set to the relevant directories, as well as a few more technical details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: Great answer. In short: No, if the key is not in `authorized_keys` on local Linux